# How to solve equations involving ceiling?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

how can an equation involving ceilings be solved? (c is a known constant, looking for n)?:

$$c=n-60\left \lceil \frac{n}{650} \right \rceil-70\left \lceil \frac{n}{600} \right \rceil-25\left \lceil \frac{n}{800} \right \rceil$$

A solution for $c=10000$ would be $n=13295$

I don't know how to deal with the ceilings. I thought about case distinction but it doesn't make sense. If you think of Max and Min values of the ceilings then you get 3 inequalities but I don't know how to fuse them.

Comment: Well, that's an inequality not an equation.  There probably isn't a single $n$ to be solved for here, just a range.  With your example, $n≥13295$ works.

Comment: Note that we always have $x+1>\lceil x\rceil≥x$ so you can get a range for the least $n$ easily.  After that, you can just search within that range for the exact value.

Comment: I changed it, so that it is an equation and what you have proposed: $n-60\left ( \frac{n}{650}+1 \right )-70\left ( \frac{n}{600}+1 \right )-25\left ( \frac{n}{800}+1 \right )< c\leq n-60 \frac{n}{650} -70 \frac{n}{600}-25 \frac{n}{800}$ Next step: $n-155<c+60\frac{n}{650}+70\frac{n}{600}+25\frac{n}{800}\leq n$ which leads to: $
n<\frac{6240}{4741}\left ( c+155 \right )\leq n+\frac{6240}{4741}*155$ and therefore: $13.161,78\leq n<13.365,78$ (For $c=10.000$) But how do I get the exact value of 13.295 now? Trying and guessing?

Comment: It's a simple search...I suppose you could break it up into cases according to the remainders on division.  But that seems tedious and error prone compared to the rapid (and nearly foolproof) search.